# Is there an alternative to org.bson.types.ObjectId that doesn't require the entire mongodb driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

So just for background I have to drop mongodb from a project (for dependency reasons, no disrespect to MongoDB!). I'm well into replacing all of the pieces with PostgreSQL equivalents but I'm a little bit stuck on `org.bson.types.ObjectId` - I don't want to replace those completely, for consistency reasons but I'm loathe to keep the whole `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.5` dependency in my project just for that.

Is there some other way to generate equivalent ObjectIDs? Or can I import just the bson types separately somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work (gradle):
`compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'bson', version: '3.12.5'`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some other way to generate equivalent ObjectIDs?

You can implement the [ObjectId spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst) yourself, it is pretty small.

Comment: Thanks - I'll consider this as a long term solution but for now importing just the bson part is fine.